# Bare metal vs API. What's the difference?

Tags: c, embedded

I've recently started learning Embedded C and have been working with FRDMKL25Z microcontroller which is ARM based. Now for interfacing a LED using switch I've came across two types of coding methods:

Bare metal:

```c
while(1) {
    if(GPIO_D->PDIR & (1<<4)) {
        /* Make the LED as OFF */
        GPIO_C->PSOR = (1 << 8);
    }
    else {
        /* Make the LED as ON */
        GPIO_C->PCOR = (1 << 8);
    }
}
```

API:

```c
while(1) {
    if(GPIO_ReadPinInput(GPIOA, 12)) {
        GPIO_SetPinsOutput(GPIOC, (1<<9));
    }
    else {
        GPIO_ClearPinsOutput(GPIOC, (1 << 9));
    }
}
```

Now both of these codes do exactly the same thing but what's the difference between them and which one is better?

Comment: This _can be_ a matter of style, and it depends on the details of the API. If for example `GPIO_SetPinsOutput` is just a macro, it might produce the exact code that you call "bare metal". -- Some API functions hide a lot of complexity and save you from writing all this boiler plate code. -- On the other hand, working directly on the registers gives you full control and most speed. -- Anyway, this is calling for opinions, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: bare metal programming means no operating system, although I am sure there are some that will argue against that.   As such api or function calls in general do not void that, you can still be without an operating system and still have function calls.

Comment: Almost by definition there is no "better" in general.  It is a matter of personal opinion.  Habits that work well for one person team, are a disaster for other individuals or teams.  One persons noise is another persons signal.

Comment: They clearly don't "do the same thing", they access different GPIO pins.  Find the source code for those functions and see for yourself. Functions encapsulate knowledge - here the knowledge of which registers to access. That can mean faster development and more portable code.  In other cases performance may be critical. There is no better

Answer (score 5):

Abstraction. If both snippets do the same thing (I'm just assuming here since I have no idea what the implementation of the GPIO functions are and what the register's description), then I would say that the only difference between them is that one is more readable than the other.
Imagine opening a new project and finding `GPIO_C->PSOR`. You'll have to find the document where the info about this register is found and see what it does. Most of the developers don't need/care about this sort of stuff (although they should know how to do it) so having an abstraction layer that covers all the "low level" part is recommended. So it's a good way to speed things up for people working on "higher levels" (drivers, application)
Plus, it's a good way to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments:

- Please note that the term "bare metal" means running without an OS. You can have an API to hardware peripherals and still have a bare metal application.
- For simple GPIO specifically, writing abstraction layers never ends up well. Hundreds of people have tried, all have failed (including yours sincerely). The former version is about as clear and readable as C gets, the latter version is just clutter and bloat.

  (AlsoCamelCaseIsHardToReadButThatsAnotherStory)
- What isn't very clear in either version is what exactly these registers do. The `PDIR` line specifically, does the code read a data input pin or a data direction register? This isn't obvious and that should have be made clear by comments - the LED comments are good but the `PDIR` line needs one too.

  In case the MCU manufacturer thought it was a brilliant idea to name a data register `PDIR`:

  > It was not a brilliant idea.

  But if this *is* a data direction register, then the name `GPIO_ReadPinInput` is horribly misleading, because then the line isn't reading the pin but the data direction setting.
- As for the second example, why isn't it using bit mask shifts consistently? Magic number 12 means... what?
- Also, both snippets have the super common shift bug: never write `1 << ...` in C because that shifts a *signed* type. `1 << 15` (8/16 bit CPU) or `1 << 31` (32/64 bit CPU) is *always* an undefined behavior bug in C. Always use `1u` suffix.
- Regarding *useful* abstraction, you should do something like

  ```
  #define LED_PORT (GPIO_C->PSOR)
  #define LED_MASK (1u << 8)

  LED_PORT |= LED_MASK;
  ```

  This allows easy re-routing of pins if needed.
- In general, don't use magic numbers! Seriously. All of these magic numbers need to be placed behind named constants.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of using a MCAL/HAL is, that your controlling logic can stay the same, no matter to what controller your bring your SW.

### No SDKs/HALs/MCALs, pure register definition file

Not using an SDK/HAL/MCAL, you have in your code always dependencies to:

- different includes of register definition files depending on the currently used chip
- different code to set/clear a pin depending on the used chip

Chip has 2 separate GPIO SET and a CLR registers:

```
GPIO_Port[port]->SET |= (1u << pin); // set on
GPIO_Port[port]->CLR |= (1u << pin); // set off
```

Chip has 1 uint16 GPIO register with upper 8 bits to clear and lower 8 bits to set a pin (or in another derivate maybe the opposite):

```
GPIO_Port[port]->DATA |= (1u << pin);     // set on
GPIO_Port[port]->DATA |= (1u << (8+pin)); // set off
```

Chip has only a single GPIO Data register, where you have to use bitwise operation for set an clear:

```
GPIO_Port[port]->DATA |= (1u << pin);  // set on
GPIO_Port[port]->DATA &= ~(1u << pin); // set off
```

Chip has each pin mapped to a separate register:

```
SIUL2->GPIO[pin1] = value1; // value 0 = off, 1 = on
SIUL2->GPIO[pin2] = value2;
```

### Vendor specific SDKs/HALs

Using different vendor specific SDKs (HALs), means, the APIs are different and includes are different depending on the currently used chip, e.g. TI MCU+-SDK or PDK, NXP SDK, STM HAL, Renesas SDK ..., but in this case, the logic to set/clear a pin within the registers is hidden.

```
// SDK1 
GPIO_WritePin(port, pin, value);
// SDK2
HAL_GPIO_SetPin(portpin_handle, value);
// SDK3
HAL2_GPIO_SetPin(pinhandle);
HAL2_GPIO_ClrPin(pinhandle);
```

All of the above code be somehow abstracted away then by the developer by using e.g.

```
#define LED_SET  GPIO_Port[LED_PORT]->SET |= (1u << LED_PIN)
#define LED_CLR  GPIO_Port[LED_PORT]->CLR |= (1u << LED_PIN)
```

A lot of developers also either add this depending on chip by compiler switches to include either one or the other header file, and define it either the one or other way.

In the end it gets also messy, no matter which of the above approaches you use.

### Cross Vendor MCAL (e.g. AUTOSAR)

In AUTOSAR, there are certain MCAL drivers defined (Adc, Dio, Port, Pwm, Mcu, Icu, Ocu, Spi, Can, Eth). They always have the same API, no matter which chip and vendor is used.

```
#include "Dio.h"

Dio_WriteChannel(DIO_CHN_LED, STD_HIGH);
Dio_WriteChannel(DIO_CHN_LED, STD_LOW);
lvl = Dio_ReadChannel(DIO_CHN_SWITCH1); // return either STD_LOW or STD_HIGH
```

Which and how the register is actually written is hidden within the Dio.c implementation. You also don't need any other register definition file depending on chip in your application.

You configure in AUTOSAR the MCAL usually by a tool, and it spits out a configuration, that is passed into Init() functions of each driver, e.g.

```
Port_Init(&Port_Config);
Adc_Init(&Adc_Config);
```

The configuration is pulled in by the drivers header file itself:

```
// -- Adc.h
#ifndef ADC_H_INCLUDED
#define ADC_H_INCLUDED
#include "Std_Types.h"
#include "Adc_Cfg.h" // contains usually pre-compile feature switches to enable/disable driver features and optional APIs
#include "Adc_PBCfg.h" // the actual drivers config (AdcGroups/AdcChannels) reference
    // the config itself is in Adc_PBCfg.c file

void Adc_Init(const Adc_ConfigType *ConfigPtr);
// ... more api ...
#endif
// end
```

Since every chip vendor is required to provide such an MCAL, and the implementation only differs within that driver modules, you application logic can rely on the same interfaces, and does not have to change across chip vendors like with the above mentioned vendor specific SDKs.

There are also some disadvantages though:

- maybe a device is not specified yet (e.g. there is no I2C driver specified in AUTOSAR)
- since also DMA is not specified, it might be hidden in the driver implementation, or you have chip/vendor specific extensions/addons
- specific HW features might not be supported by driver, due to the standard feature & API specification unless an non-AUTOSAR extension/addon is provided by the vendor, e.g. updating a PWM configuration over DMA from a predefined set of PWM settings